# convert a unix epoch timestamp into a formatted excel date and time with openpyxl

Tags: python, datetime, openpyxl

I have a data set where one column is a captured time as a UNIX epoch.  I'd like to mangle that with openpyxl into a specific format:  in my case I want MM/DD MM:SS where "June 14 2020 03:05:07 PM" would display as `06/14 15:05`.

Answer (score 1):

- define a [NamedStyle](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) that represents the output format you want.
- use [iter_cols](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) (any other iterator) to loop over the cells you want to format.
- create a python [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) from the value in that cell
- openpyxl has a [library](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.datetime.html) to convert UNIX datetimes to excel datetimes (excel uses some nonstandard format, of course...)
- apply the desired style to each cell.

```
# ws is an existing openpyxl Worksheet instance
custom_datetime = openpyxl.styles.NamedStyle(name='datetime', number_format='MM/DD HH:MM')
for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=1): 
    for cell in col:
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(cell.value)
        cell.value = openpyxl.utils.datetime.to_excel(dt)
        cell.style = custom_datetime
```

Comment: Please update your question, don't post an answer.

Comment: @PedroLobito I think this is supposed to be an self-answered question?

Comment: Yep.  I didn't find anything in search and figured out how, so I self-answered.  No point stealing here  ;-)